# Saving console logs to GCP

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

I am using nodeJs application in GCP CloudRun environment.
And using `console.log` to log some of the important information to GCP logging.

I have the below query regarding the logging:

- Will it make any difference in charge/cost if I stringify the logs rather than directly doing `console.log`.

Thank you

Comment: You are charged on the volume of log that you ingest. More you logs, more verbose are your logs more you pay.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing), logs are priced by **data volume**.

So if signifying your logs changes the volume of the logs than yes, it will affect your GCP cost.